# Is there a way to dynamically generate members in a TypeScript definition?

Tags: typescript

I don't think the title for this question is very good, but I had trouble coming up with something better, so it'll do for now.

I'm also fairly sure that what I want isn't supported, but I'd love to be proved wrong!

I have an API I'm calling, and it varies the member names in the object returned based on the query.

e.g.

```
GetInfo(languages?:string[]);
GetInfo() => { name: "Cologne" };
GetInfo(["en", "de"]) => { name: "Cologne", name_en: "Cologne", name_de: "Köln" };
```

Is there a way to create a definition that will "generate" the name_{language} members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for manipulation of property names in this way (ie. concatenate a string to another string and have this be a type checked property).

The best you can do is not just return an object with the properties being the same name as the language names:

```
function GetInfo<T extends string>(langs: T[]): Record<T | 'default', string>{
  return null as any;
}
let values = GetInfo(["en", "de"]) // values is  { en: string; de: string; default: string  }
values.default
values.de
values.en
```

There is an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13969) on GitHub that suggest adding support for string literal manipulations, but it's nowhere on the roadmap for now

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, and link to that issue.

Comment: @AndyJ add your +1 to the issue it probably matters to the team when they consider what to implement next :)